# JFrame doesn't displayed the JMenuBar

Tags: java, user-interface

Here is the code:

```
private void initComponent() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    setTitle("Pizza Order System");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1000, 900));
    menu = new JMenu();
    menuItem = new JMenuItem();
    menuItem.setText("About");
    menu.add(menuItem);
    Pane = new JDesktopPane();
    menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    menuBar.add(menu);
    mainPanel = new JPanel();
    GroupLayout panelLayout = new GroupLayout(mainPanel);
    mainPanel.setLayout(panelLayout);
    setJMenuBar(menuBar);
    GroupLayout layout = new GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(Pane)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap()
                    .addComponent(mainPanel, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addContainerGap())
            );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(5, 5, 5)
                    .addComponent(mainPanel, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(Pane, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 804, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            );
    pack();
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);

}
```

For my code, I already initialize the menu, menuitem, menuBar, add the menuitem into menu, add the menu into menubar, and set the menubar already,it seems like everything looks good, but JmenuBar doesn't wanna show up....

Answer (score 1):

Your `menu = new JMenu();` does not provide a String argument, so it has nothing to display. Try changing it to `menu = new JMenu("sometext");` and see if it appears.

Answer (score -1):

Simply use this code you get ...that  here this code is for making the notepad like structure you can try this  use   ..

```
        import javax.swing.*;
        import java.awt.*;
         import java.awt.event.*;
       class JNotepad extends JFrame implements ActionListener
      {
          JMenuBar mb;
         JMenu f,e,fo,v,h;
         JMenuItem f_i1,f_i2,f_i3,f_i4,e_i1,e_i2,fo_i1,v_i1,h_i1;
         JTextArea t;
         public JNotepad()
       {
         mb=new JMenuBar();
         setSize(500,500);
         setTitle("JNotepad");
         setVisible(true);
          f=new JMenu("File");
          e=new JMenu("Edit");
         fo=new JMenu("Format");
         v=new JMenu("View");
          h=new JMenu("Help");
          f_i1=new JMenuItem("new");
          f_i2=new JMenuItem("open");
          f_i3=new JMenuItem("save");
          f_i4=new JMenuItem("save as");
          e_i1=new JMenuItem("undo");
          e_i2=new JMenuItem("paste");
          fo_i1=new JMenuItem("font");
          v_i1=new JMenuItem("status bar");
          h_i1=new JMenuItem("view help");
          mb.add(f);
          mb.add(e);
          mb.add(fo);
          mb.add(v);
          mb.add(h);
          f.add(f_i1);
          f.add(f_i2);
          f.add(f_i3);
          f.add(f_i4);
          e.add(e_i1);
          e.add(e_i2);
          fo.add(fo_i1);
          v.add(v_i1);
          h.add(h_i1);
          setJMenuBar(mb);
          }
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
          {
          if(ae.getSource()==f_i1)
          {
       JNotepad obj=new JNotepad();
       obj.setVisible(true);
       setVisible(false);
       }}
       public static void main(String []args)
       {
       JNotepad stu =new JNotepad();
       }}
```

setJMenubar(mb);  use at the last of contructer then it will appear.......as used in this code.

Comment: Actually this doesn't answer the question. In addition I don't think the OP wants to do a Notepad. The naming of your widgets is also quite bad in my opinion.

Comment: yes i agree with u but you can take naming of JMenuItem as your desire...and you can use only the statement setJmenuBar(mb);   at the end of costructer then it will appear..

Comment: The OP has used `setJMenuBar(menuBar);`, therefore this is not the problem.

Comment: yes i again agree with u becouse i also suffer from same problem ...but before i use setJMenuBar(mb); at starting of the costructer then it did not appear but when i use at the last of costructer as give code then it become appear..